# avoid GET_ENTITY call on bindElement for data already loaded in get_entityset

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a Master Detail Detail-Detail Application:

- Master: List of Users
- Detail: Table with Qualifications of the user
- Detail-Detail: Form to Edit the Qualifications

In the Detail View I have all the informations I need for the Form in the Detail-Detail view.

when I get the path of the selected listItem in the Detail View and then do a bindElement in my DetailDetail View a new Request for GET_ENTITY is called in my backend. How can I avoid this call as I already have all the data I need in my Detail View?

I could work around this issue by using a local JSON Model for the data I want to edit, but as I would like to use .hasPendingChanges in my Edit View I guess I need to bind to the original oDataModel, but as mentioned would like to avoid the GET_ENTITY backend call.

Answer (score 0):

When you are binding an OData context if you call an entity the you will end in a request. i.e:

Think in a /Order('123') context then you need to bind another entity like /Order('123')/Location this is going to trigger a network request but in the case of any data like ID /Order('123')/ID this dont do any network request because properties do not trigger requests.

### [OData Model](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2)

> Requests to the back end are triggered by list bindings
> (ODataListBinding), context bindings (ODataContextBinding), and CRUD
> functions provided by the ODataModel. Property bindings
> (ODataPropertyBindings) do not trigger requests.

As you said you can workaround it using a JSONModel but then you will need to maintain two models, create validations, etc.

Hope this clarification helps.